# How to change interval value in React

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I've tried changing the interval value when using ReactJs, but can't seem to get it to work. I've looked it up but haven't found anything useful (or maybe I didn't get to it while reading). I have most of my code inside a class component.

My code looks like this:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tickS: 1000,

      ...
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      this.state.tickS
    );
  }
  tick(){
    this.setState({
      ...

      tickS: 10**Math.log10(this.state.tickS + this.state.clicksChange),

      ...
    });
  }
}
```

It does work for using `1000` milliseconds, but when i try to redefine the state of `tickS`, it doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to update how often the interval fires?

Comment: Not how often it fires, i want it to change constantly, so each interval is slower than the one before. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the interval of `setInterval`. Instead, you can take another approach and use `setTimeout` for the same purpose. Check out the example:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ticks = 1000;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timeoutID = setTimeout(
      () => this.tick(),
      this.tick
    );
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      ...
    });

    this.ticks = 10 ** Math.log10(this.ticks + this.state.clicksChange),

    this.timeoutID = setTimeout(
      () => this.tick(),
      this.ticks
    ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, happy to help :)